# Doctrine 2 + ZF2 : Single Sign-On

Tags: php, authentication, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, single-sign-on

I'm currently making the new version of my company's website using ZF2 and Doctrine 2.

I have some modules, (Application, Account, Project Manager, Support, etc.) and only one (Account) provides the login/logout and every Auth functions. The problem, is that with Doctrine2, the Auth isn't very easy to use... The docs isn't very descriptive too.

If someone can help me, I would like to know how I use it with `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`...

### What I already know

#### In `Module.php`:

```
'factories' => array(
    'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function ($sm) {
         $auth = new AuthenticationService();
         $authAdapter = null; // What I do here??

         $auth->setAdapter($authAdapter);
         
         return $auth;
    },
    // ...
),
// ...
```

What I need to do to get the AuthService in every module, without "factory-sing" in each one...

**Note:** I'll be using the Identity View Helper...

Comment: The factory `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` IS known to EVERY Module already. The configuration from ALL MODULES is merged into ONE BIG CONFIG!

Comment: Si i only need to configure it in the module Account (the first one initialized) and it will work in everyone?

Comment: Yep. You basically register it to the `ServiceManager`, which in ZF1 Terms would be similar to the `Registry`

Comment: Can I register it from the `application.config.php` or in a `xxxx.global/local.php` or i need to register it in the Module.php? In clear, where and what I write to register it? (Post as an answer if you want rep.! ;) )

Comment: [My Blog about "Understanding ZF2 Configuration"](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/) might help you in getting your answer ;) (and an comment upvote is enough already ;))

Comment: I already added few of your blogs to my iCloud Reading List ;) You seem pretty advanced in ZF2...!

Comment: What do you expect from this bounty? Did you check out existing Authentication Modules like ZfcUser? Maybe that will help you better in understanding things.

Comment: I need to write my own module for secret purpose...

Comment: In clear, I want to know how to use Doctrine Auth with Zend... I'm new to ZF2...

Comment: I [heard that Documentation usually helps](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/authentication.md) ;)

Comment: That's a good start (didn't found this docs). But now if I want to use DB Sessions? How I setup them in Doctrine Auth?? Also, please post your full answer as an true answer... I will give you the bounty ;)

Comment: I would use ZfcUser, which get along very well with doctrine, and the override or extend whatever you need to make it as custom as you need